# Why session_start is needed when using session?

Tags: php, session

Why I can use `setcookie` without any preparation while need a `session_start()` before using `$_SESSION`?And I think works they do are similar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because [setcookie()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) *defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers*. That's a completely different thing than what [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) does, e.g. *creating a session or resuming the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.*

The first just adds something to the header and sends it *to* the browser, while the other gets the Session ID *from* $_COOKIEs or $_GET or $_POST and then tries finding the session file in the [session_save_path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) and when found unserializing the values of it into $_SESSION and if not, create a new session, probably using `setcookie` in the process to set the Session Id.

See the [chapter on Sessions in the PHP Manual.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

---

<sub>**Edit** Like @Felix correctly points out below, the session is not necessarily saved in a file. It's not that important though, because the argument stays the same: `session_start` will find and (re-) initialize your session data, while `setcookie` just does what the name implies.</sub>

Comment: I have got it.Thanks for the quality answers.

Answer (score 1):

For explanation see the reply before mine.
If you just don't want to call the start_session() function have a look at this setting in the php.ini:
[session.auto_start](http://de.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start)

Answer (score 1):

The session data is not necessarily stored in a file as Gordon says. With [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) you can define your own backend that should store the values, e.g. in a database.

All this data retrieving is handled with `session_start()`. This way you can easily change you backend without breaking your application.

Note: This is only one reason for `session_start()`, and again it does lot more then just setting cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The session data is not necessarily stored in a file as Gordon says. With `session_set_save_handler()` you can define your own back end that should store the values, e.g. in a database.

All this data retrieving is handled with `session_start()`. This way you can easily change you back end without breaking your application.

Note: This is only one reason for `session_start()`, and again it does lot more then just setting cookies.