# SESSION variable reset when changing page

Tags: php, session, reset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why session_start is needed when using session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460979/why-session-start-is-needed-when-using-session)

I'm doing my first login-secured site and I want to store a simple boolean in the session superglobal. I know I set it correctly since I can dump it while I'm in the same script but when I change page $_SESSION array is emptied.

I'm running an Nginx / Debian / php5 setup.

I've seen that there may be requiered files or directories for the session variable to be stored on the server's side when using specific hosting but as I am on a vps it should not be my case.

It goes this way:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['nom'] = 'Eric';
   var_dump($_SESSION); //wich outputs correctly 
?>
[the login form]
```

Then I submit my form, and I var_dump $_SESSION on the first line of the target page but it is null so it is not even set. The session seems completely closed except that I have the $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] displaying the correct id.

I don't know how to be more clear or what detail to add... Just ask if needed!

Comment: Did you call `session_start()` on the tarfet page too? You must call it on every script that accesses the session.

Comment: Oh god I like those simple answers! I thought that the session_start() was spawning a session if that was available and accessible for all the session_cache_expire value but did not know that... So dumd of me I searched so long not finding it I don't know how... Thanks!

Comment: You might consider session auto-start.  I believe that is settable in php.ini, but since the default is to have that off, your code would be less portable if you depend on it.

Comment: See if this article is helpful .http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/A_2391-PHP-login-logout-and-easy-access-control.html